# Copy days report to weekly

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem. 
I have two workbooks. The first one is `Workbook A`, which contain information about days in a month. 
The second one is Weekly Summary workbook, where I need to do weekly reports from `Workbook A`. There I would like to have VBA code, that copies the information about week days and paste the range from each day into `Sheet1` of the Weekly Summary Workbook.

Can someone help me?

Here is an example...

Information about Days:

[image: Information about Days]

Week summary:

[image: Week summary]

Comment: Could you post an example of how your two tables look like? It'd be best to edit it into your question.

Comment: We can easily help you with this, but we need to have see your sheet, post a in image of the sheets and also post the marco you wrote until now. You can actually even record the marco on one of the weeks, which will get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code that was *not* tested, but should give you a good idea to start writing your macro:

```
Dim wkBookLog As WorkBook
Dim wkBookWeekly As WorkBook
Dim datestring As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rowCount As Long
Dim CountDays As Integer

Set wkBookLog = Workbooks("Workbook A")
Set wkBookWeekly = Workbooks("Weekly Summary")
rowCount=0

For each s in wkBookLog.Sheets
    datestring = s.Range("C2").Text 
    LastRow = Range("A4").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    s.Range("A4:A" & Cstr(LastRow)).Copy wsBookWeekly.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Cstr(4+rowCount))
    s.Range("C2").Copy wsBookWeekly.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Cstr(4+rowCount) & _
        ":B" & Cstr(4+rowCount+LastRow))
    rowCount=rowCount+LastRow+1
    CountDays=CountDays+1
    If CountDays=7 Then
        CountDays=0
        rowCount=0
        wsBookWeekly.ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    End If

Next s
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much ... :)
I will try it, and i believe, that this code help me to solve the problem...